# String manipulation with JavaScript from the end of the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I've been having trouble trying to apply different JavaScript string manipulation solutions to my specific problem:

```
string str = ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4"
```

From the end of the string, I want to remove all the way up to the first `:` that is found.

**1 removal**:

```
":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 "
```

**2 removals**:

```
":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |"
```

**3 removals**:

```
":2 E/4 "
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide us with code that you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using `String.split`, `Array.slice` and `Array.join` functions:

```
/**
 * @param string str Input string with 'colons'
 * @param number removals Number of removals
 * @returns string
 */
var sliceToColon = function (str, removals) {
    var parts = str.split(":");
    return parts.slice(0, -removals).join(":");
}

console.log(sliceToColon(":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4", 1)); // :2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 
console.log(sliceToColon(":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4", 2)); // :2 E/4 :2 G/4 |
console.log(sliceToColon(":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4", 3)); // :2 E/4
```

Comment: I'll be implementing something similar to this, this actually helped me think about a future problem I will be facing too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lastindexof()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) to get the last occurance of `":"` and then extract all the caracters before the position of that index using [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

```js
var str = ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4";
var n = str.lastIndexOf(":");
console.log(str.substring(0, n));
```

Comment: Cool and simple! I can't believe I didn't think of this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction(':2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4','2')">Click</button>
<script>
function myFunction(str,n) {
var x,y;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {     
    x=str.lastIndexOf(":");
    y=str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf(":"));
str= y;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  y;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option, though a little more verbose than many, is the following:

```
function removeLastNSections(opts) {

  // the default settings,
  // text:       String, must be user-supplied;
  //             the string to be split and from
  //             which 'sections' should be removed.
  // separator:  String,the character upon which
  //             string should be split.
  // n:          Number, or numeric String (4 or '4'),
  //             the number of 'sections' to remove.
  var settings = {
    'text' : null,
    'separator' : ':',
    'n' : 1
  },
  haystack,
  numSections;

  // updating the defaults with user-supplied values:
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(function(key){
    settings[key] = opts[key];
  });

  // if settings.text exists:
  if (settings.text) {

    // we split the user-supplied string of text on
    // occurrences of the separator:
    haystack = settings.text.split( settings.separator );

    // an integer for the length of the haystack array:
    numSections = haystack.length;

    // we slice the haystack array, taking all elements from
    // the first (index: 0) to the index resulting from the
    // sum of the number of elements in the array minus the
    // number of 'sections' to remove:        
    return haystack.slice(0, numSections - settings.n )
      // and join those array-elements back into a
      // a string by joining them together with the
      // separator:
      .join( settings.separator );
  }

  return '';
}
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text' : ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4"
  })
); // => :2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text' : ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4",
    'n': 1
  })
); // => :2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text' : ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4",
    'n' : 2
  })
); // => :2 E/4 :2 G/4 |
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text' : ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4",
    'n' : 3
  })
); // => :2 E/4
```

```js
function removeLastNSections(opts) {
  var settings = {
      'text': null,
      'separator': ':',
      'n': 1
    },
    haystack,
    numSections;

  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(function(key) {
    settings[key] = opts[key];
  });

  if (settings.text) {
    haystack = settings.text.split(settings.separator);
    numSections = haystack.length;

    return haystack.slice(0, numSections - settings.n).join(settings.separator);
  }

  return '';
}
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text': ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4"
  })
);
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text': ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4",
    'n': 1
  })
);
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text': ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4",
    'n': 2
  })
);
console.log(
  removeLastNSections({
    'text': ":2 E/4 :2 G/4 |:2 G/4 :2 F/4",
    'n': 3
  })
);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Thanks David! I like the verbose explanation a lot, no biggie.